# Strapi v4 too much nested data

Tags: graphql, strapi

I'm rewriting strapi v3 queries to v4 (GraphQL), and with new fields 'data' and 'attributes', I have a problem going too much deep into nested objects, an example of how data looks:

```js
user {
  data {
    id
    attributes {
      company {
        data {
          id
          attributes {
            location {
              data {
                id
                ...
              }
          }
      }
    
    }
  }
}
```

Am I missing something in the documentation, is there a way to avoid this much nesting, should I restructure data in Model, or?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known pain point for many, but no immediate official solution in sight. Gotta deal with it.

https://forum.strapi.io/t/discussion-regarding-the-complex-response-structure-for-rest-graphql-developer-experience/13400/35

Comment: Anyone have a good work around?

Comment: So far my best solution is to just try to break up stuff in many components and flatten the data when its passed into the component. Ex.
```
{records.data.map(({ id, attributes }) => (
   <Record key={id} {...{ ...attributes, id }} />
 ))}
```

Answer (score 1):

My friend, that's the way now:

```
user.data.attributes.company.data.attributes.location.data
```

Answer (score 0):

For solve this you can install the [strapi-plugin-transformer](https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-transformer)

And pass the needed configurations to remove `data` and `attributes` from the response.

Comment: I think this is just for API requests not GraphQL?

Comment: There's no way to do from the Strapi server with graphql, but there are solutions, you can use the following package, it will be able to remove the Strapi wrappers:

https://github.com/Dave136/smapper

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the deeply nested structures in your Strapi v4 GraphQL queries using the `strapi-flatten-graphql` library (I am the author). This lightweight TypeScript library provides functions to flatten the nested GraphQL responses, making them more concise and easier to work with.

To get started, install the library using npm:

```
npm install strapi-flatten-graphql
```

Import the necessary functions from the library:

```
import { flattenEntityResponse } from 'strapi-flatten-graphql';
```

Then, use the `flattenEntityResponse` function to flatten your GraphQL responses:

```
const response = /* Your GraphQL response object */;
const flattenedResponse = flattenEntityResponse(response);

// Use the flattened response in your application
console.log(flattenedResponse);
```

The `flattenEntityResponse` function handles the transformation of the nested structure into a simpler, flattened format. It also includes TypeScript typings to ensure type safety while working with the flattened data.

By using `strapi-flatten-graphql`, you can streamline your Strapi v4 GraphQL queries and improve the readability and maintainability of the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new package to resolve this issue [strapi-flatten-graphql](https://github.com/ciekawy/strapi-flatten-graphql)

This will eliminate the `data` and `attributes`

Please check the package documentation for more details

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [graphql](https://github.com/GavinXue/strapi-study-cases/tree/main/src/plugins/graphql)

git clone https://github.com/GavinXue/strapi-study-cases.git

copy folder graphql from plugin on your project inside plugin also extension/graphql and set configuracion on config/plugins also on index

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of annoying, but you can deal with it in Typescript. Below is my `interfaces.tsx` file. It has more information than needed, but it works well. The idea is to define a generic interface with a data field which will contain an object with an id and attributes and be able to use it for any Generic type `T`:

```
// ---------------------- Custom interfaces and types ----------------------

export interface StateObject<T>  extends Type<T> {
    temp: StrapiObject<T>;
}

export interface Type<T> {
    data: StrapiObject<T>;
}

export interface TypeArray<T> {
    data: StrapiObject<T>[];
}

export interface StrapiObject<T> {
    id: number,
    attributes: T
}

interface Image {
    url: string;
}

type ImageField = Type<Image>;

export interface DivisionAttributes {
    name: string;
    createdAt: string;
    updatedAt: string;
    publishedAt: string;
    locale: string;
    categories: Category | CategoryArray;
    medical_products: MedicalProduct | MedicalProductArray;
    photo?: ImageField; // Adjusted to match the Type structure
    localizations: Type<any>; // Assuming localizations can be of any structure
}

export interface CategoryAttributes {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    divisions: Division | DivisionArray;
    medical_products: MedicalProduct | MedicalProductArray;
    image: ImageField; // Adjusted to match the Type structure
}

interface MedicalProductAttributes {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    price: number;
    photo: ImageField; // Adjusted for consistency
    localizations: Type<any>; // Adjusted to match the Type structure
}


export type AnimationStage = 'idle' | 'fadingIn' | 'fadingOut' | 'error';

// ~ Hack to get the response type of the Strapi API right 
export type DivisionArray = TypeArray<DivisionAttributes>;
export type CategoryArray = TypeArray<CategoryAttributes>;
export type MedicalProductArray = TypeArray<MedicalProductAttributes>;

export type Division = Type<DivisionAttributes>;
export type Category = Type<CategoryAttributes>;
export type MedicalProduct = Type<MedicalProductAttributes>;
```